# Amsterdam to Paris but drop off at Brussels with Thalys

Tags: paris, amsterdam, brussels, thalys

I'm trying to book a ticket from Amsterdam to Brussels with Thalys, but they are all sold out even though I'm three months in advance. But I can buy tickets from Amsterdam to Paris and I can see that the train stops at Brussels (probably to take more passengers).

Can I buy a ticket from Amsterdam to Paris, but drop off at Brussels?
Are the luggages checked-in ? If yes, how can I get them out at Brussels?

Comment: That's odd. Where did you check? NS International? AFAIK, Thalys tickets cannot even be bought more than three months in advance…

Comment: I checked on Thalys website. I'm exactly 3 months in advance. Tickets are all sold out except for more expensive first class or with flexible option

Comment: OK, I see, “sold out” might be a bit of misnomer, there are obviously tickets still to be had, even in second class. It's the cheapest fare that's sold out (or perhaps wasn't even available at all, for commercial reasons). Funny that a ticket all the way to Paris should be cheaper.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can do that. There is no checked luggage, so there is nothing wrong with buying a train ticket to Paris, but getting of in Brussels.

Having said that, you might want to check other options. There is the cheaper train to Brussels. You can buy tickets for the train to Brussels at any Dutch railway station. This train is without reservation.

There is also the [idbus](http://www.idbus.com/line/amsterdam-brussels) with regular service to Brussels from Amsterdam.

If you are flying in to Amsterdam with KLM, there is also the option to continue your journey. As with some other [train stations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_IATA-indexed_railway_stations) Brussels has an airport code (ZYR) and at some airlines it is possible to buy an airline ticket to ZYR. You would however continue your journey from Amsterdam airport to Brussels on the Thalys. The beauty of this trick is that when your incoming flight is delayed, they simply put you on the next train.